# Trying to use "The Amazing Audio Engine" and "AudioStreamer" at the same app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

At the app i'm currently working on, there is a "studio" when you can make some sound effect, and for that i'm using "The amazing audio engine".

And there is an option to listen to songs by stream too.
Unfortunately the amazing audio engine doesn't contain "streaming" functionality, so i'm using the "AudioStreamer" calss.

I don't know why but the two don't work well together for me.
Each off them alone work great, but at the moment i try to play some audio on the amazing audio engine, stop, and move to stream, then move back to the audio engine, the sound doesn't play any more! no sound!

I checked already that i call "Stop" on every class, and make it "nil".
I allocate each of them every time again before they play.

I'm out of options, and thinking maybe it has something to do with core audio that both of them use? 
Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT**

What i found is, this happens only when i use the "Stop" method of the "AudioStreamer"!
Can any won explain way?

**Edit second**

Found the answer!

This was solved by outmark This:

```
        /*
        while (state != AS_INITIALIZED)
    {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }
       */


   // And adding this:

   AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);
```

To the "stop" method, still, do not really understand why...

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time after calling an audio stop method or function for it to really stop all the audio units (while the buffers get emptied by the hardware, etc.).  You often can't restart audio until after this (a short) delay.

Comment: Thats sounds logic, but the thing is, after playing the both of them, the great audio engine did not make any sound no matter how long did i wait, very strange..